# Передача картинки и текста не работает

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Добрый день. В MVC используется функция с контроллера.

```
Function Yashare(img As String, txt As String)
        Dim Ya As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
        Ya.Append("<div class=""ya-share2""")
        Ya.Append("data-services=""vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus""")
        Ya.Append("data-counter=""""")
        Ya.Append("data-image=" & img & "")
        Ya.Append("data-description=" & txt & "")
        Ya.Append("></div>")
        Return (Ya.ToString)
    End Function
```

Вызов следующий

```
@Html.Action("Yashare", "Home", New With {.img = Model.Images, .txt = Model.Text})
```

Титл и ссылка нормальные. Картинок нет (они есть точно, но при наведении на поделиться, вид images=(Collection) что в принципе верно.)

И текста нет.

Все есть точно, сайт рботает и данные есть.

Вот это

```
var myShare = document.getElementById('my-share');

var share = Ya.share2(myShare, {
    content: {
        url: 'https://yandex.com'      
    }
   // здесь вы можете указать и другие параметры
});
```

не могу использовать, т.к. в представлении,  разметка генерится на лету

вот этой штукой @Html.Action...

---

Хорошо. перефразирую так.

```
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,twitter,facebook,gplus" data-description='текст объявления по ссылке'  data-image='@Url.Content("~/AdImages/" & Model.Images)' data-counter></div>
```

Так все работает, кроме картинок. Не передает в ВК картинки, а в гиперссылке вот такой фрагмент есть 
images=(Collection)

Comment: Пока что из вопроса непонятно примерно ничего.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте добавить OpenGraph к своей странице.
Вы сможете задать собственное описание и заголовок для поста, также сможете указать картинку.

Прочитайте [Базовое описание](http://ogp.me/).
Добавьте на страницу (пример):

```
<head>
    ...
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com">
    <meta property="og:locale" content="ru_RU">

    <meta property="og:title" content="Текст названия">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Текст описания">

    <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/img/picture.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1280">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="720">
    ...
</head>
```

Facebook рекомендует указывать тип изображения и его размеры.
Как будет выглядеть ваш пост вы можете посмотреть в [facebook object debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)
На этой странице можно найти [дополнительные объекты](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph) (продукция, рестораны, и еще несколько полезных объектов).
Длинна передаваемого описания переменная (зависит от места отображения)

**Добавлено**
Обратил внимание, что вы используете @Url.Content() для ссылки на картинку. Эта функция создает относительный URL. Задайте абсолютный адрес с доменом и протоколом для картинки.

Comment: Да видел что рекомендуют OG. Хорошо, объявил OG, мета переменные прописал, див оставил такой <div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,twitter,facebook,gplus" в передаваемой странице вообще ничего не меняется, т.е. не срабатывает OG видимо

Comment: Вы, случайно, не с localhost проверяете работу шаринга? С него оно может работать не корректно. Вы проверяли в object debugger (если сайт доступен в интернете)? У яндекса есть инструмент проверки микроразметки по куску кода [ссылка](https://old.webmaster.yandex.ru/microtest.xml)

Comment: Спасибо за наводки, указал метатег  <meta property="og:image" content="http://*/AdImages/" + @Model.Images> Но яндекс такой путь видит http://ogp.me/ns#image = http://*/AdImages/. Т.е. имя фала не берет все-равно

Comment: А вообщем если удалить вообще OG, то то же самое. Короче не работает OG на странице. Даже если DISCRIPTION поменять в OG ничего не меняется

Comment: Может вам действующий пример поможет? В начале года делал сайт [сайт](http://z60x60.ru/). Внизу блок с кнопками yandex share. Выберите VK и посмотрите что получается, потом в head загляните.

Comment: AndrewB, вот то же самое и у меня(  А как передаете картинку в метатег?

Comment: Тот сайт статичный, она в html прописана. В asp.net передаю через секцию 
`@section og {
 <meta property="og:image" content="@Url.Content($"~/img/{p.PhotoPath}", true)">
}` В мастер странице  стоит RenderSection, а Url.Content дописан свой, чтобы выдавал абсолютный путь (с http:// и т.д.).

Comment: AndrewB. Спасибо, но так же нет. <meta property="og:image" content="@Url.Content($"~/AdImages/{Model.Images}")">. И у меня TRUE валиться в ошибку, что лишний аргумент. А если картинок несколько, должно работать? Просто у меня она не одна, а так, всё так же как и у Вас

Comment: Короче, указал статично всё, хрен. Ну что может не так быть, вообще не понимаю <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://dkz-city.ihb.by">
    <meta property="og:locale" content="ru_RU">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://dkz-city.ihb.by/AdImages/18a8315c-4f8e-471a-bc74-29c8d98fb036.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg">

Comment: Валидатор яндекса видит все ок rdfanode
resource = http://www.dkz-city.ihb.by/Home/Ad/16
http://ogp.me/ns#title = Продам
http://ogp.me/ns#type = website
http://ogp.me/ns#image:height = 720
http://ogp.me/ns#url = http://dkz-city.ihb.by
http://ogp.me/ns#image:width = 1280
http://ogp.me/ns#image = http://dkz-city.ihb.by/AdImages/18a8315c-4f8e-471a-bc74-29c8d98fb036.jpg
http://ogp.me/ns#image:type = image/jpeg
http://ogp.me/ns#locale = ru_RU
http://ogp.me/ns#description = Полное описание по ссылке

Comment: В `og` для каждой картинки нужно задавать отдельное свойство `og:image` и все ему сопутствующие. [Ссылка на документацию](http://ogp.me/#array). Т.о. у вас будет один или несколько подобных мета тегов для изображений.

Comment: Нет, я вооще не пойму что не так, я выше указал, что картинка указана статически, но ни картинка, ни DISCRIPTION не подхватывается. Это все указано в View, которым и нужно поделиться.

Comment: Страница, которой вы хотите поделиться могла быть закеширована соц сетью, поэтому изменений не видно. Попробуйте проверить в другой соц сети или поищите как очистить кеш в ВК.

Comment: Andrew, так я смотрю, что счетчик на Вашем сайте так же не работает через OG?

Comment: Счетчик добавлять не захотели. Как счетчик связан с OG я не знаю. Не думаю, что есть такая связь, но лучше погуглить.

Comment: Andrew, спасибо за наводки, была включена защита от хотлинкинга у хостера, вот и всё c OG(

Comment: Можете сказать какой хостер, если не секрет, и удалось ли решить с ним этот вопрос?

Comment: Проблема решилась отключением, хостера прошу прощения - нет