# В блоке "Поделиться" не отображается текст параметра data-description для Вконтакте

Tags: вконтакте, ya-share2

не могу понять почему не отображается текст параметра data-description. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём дело.

[image]

Разметка блока выглядит так.

```
<div
    class="ya-share2"
    data-services="vkontakte,twitter,facebook,gplus"
    data-description="дескрипшен"
    data-url="https://rgloss.ru/posti/post1.html"
    data-title="Преображение Виктории"
    data-image="https://rgloss.ru/img/t1-1.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача картинки и текста не работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/557257/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82)

Comment: Не все сети позволяют [передать им параметры в явном виде](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/troubleshooting-docpage/#no-parameters).

Answer (score -1):

В стилях нужно написать content: attr(data-description)

"... Само отображение происходит с помощью псевдоэлемента ::after и свойства content, значением которого как раз и выступает функция attr()..."

[Здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/atribut-data)

Comment: Здравствуйте, пробую писать 'content: attr(data-description)'
Сначала попробовал в style="" прямо в div, не получилось
Описание всё так же ссылкой отображается
Через класс тоже так же.
Уточню, мне нужно описание в репосте ВК
Помогите, мучаюсь уже долго
На сайте по установке этих кнопок прописано так писать, но совсем не работает.