# Блок "поделиться" использует не ту картинку

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

При публикации в Facebook записи с ссылкой на товар в моём интернет-магазине отображается картинка с главной страницы сайта. Хочу, чтобы было изображение самого товара. Как этого добиться?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача картинки и текста не работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/557257/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82)

Answer (score 0):

1. в фейсбуке есть [ресурс специальный](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) для обновления этих картинок
2. теги [opengraph](http://ogp.me/) должны присутствовать в разделе `<head>`
3. и вообще кнопки поделиться надо самому писать.